# Windows equivalent command for linux's 'touch' to update file timestamp

Tags: linux, windows, command

In Linux based systems, if I've existing file and I just want to change its timestamp. I use following command -

```
touch <file-name>
```

Is there any equivalent command in Windows to just change file's timestamp?

Comment: this question was asked before.
Take a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch/764721#764721

Comment: I missed it. THanks @Bluescreenterror for pointing it.

Comment: there is also a touch step for pipelines

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'touch.exe' tiny and stand alone command from Steve Miller's *Win32 Console ToolBox 1.1* (freeware) from  https://stevemiller.net/apps/

Comment: It does. I'm using it regularly on many Win 7-10 NTFS systems. Remember it's a DOS command you have to run from command prompt (NOTE: option /t is adjusted to UTC time, so "/d 10:10:10" from UTC+1 location like Italy becomes 9:10:10). If you're looking for a Windows integrated UI you can try shell extension named 'SKTimeStamp'

Comment: Ok mate, thanks for the update... for some reason its doesn't work for me personally... went with: ni file.php, file2.css, file3.html    - which works great and serves my needs ;)